# With argparse it it possible to process arguments only up to the last non-positional argument?

Tags: python, command-line-arguments, argparse, positional-argument

I'm writing a tool which passes arguments to another command provided with the arguments like this:

```
foo --arg1 -b -c bar -v --number=42
```

In this example `foo` is my tool and `--arg1 -b -c` should be the arguments parsed by `foo`, while `-v --number=42` are the arguments going to `bar`, which is the *command* called by `foo`.

So this is quite similar to `strace` where you can provide arguments to `strace` while still providing a command with custom arguments.

`argparse` provides `parse_known_arguments()` but it will parse *all* arguments it knows even those coming after `bar`.

Some tools use a special syntax element (e.g. `--`) to separate arguments with different semantics, but since I know `foo` will only process names arguments, I'd like to avoid this.

That can't be too hard to manually find the first argument you might think, and this is what I'm currently doing:

```py
parser.add_argument("--verbose", "-v", action="store_true")
all_args = args or sys.argv[1:]
with suppress(StopIteration):
    split_at = next(i for i, e in enumerate(all_args) if not e.startswith("-" ))
    return parser.parse_args(all_args[:split_at]), all_args[split_at:]
raise RuntimeError("No command provided")
```

And this works with the example I've provided. But with `argparse` you can specify arguments with values which can but don't have to be provided with a `=`:

```
foo --file=data1 --file data2 bar -v --number=42
```

So here it would be much harder to manually identify `data2` to be a value for the second `--file` argument, and `bar` to be the first positional argument.

My current approach is to manually split arguments (backwards) and see, if all 'left hand' arguments successfully parse:

```py
def parse_args():
    class MyArgumentParser(ArgumentParser):
        def error(self, message: str) -> NoReturn:
            raise RuntimeError()

    parser = MyArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("--verbose", "-v", action="store_true")
    parser.add_argument("--with-value", type=str)

    all_args = sys.argv[1:]
    for split_at in (i for i, e in reversed(list(enumerate(all_args))) if not e.startswith("-")):
        with suppress(RuntimeError):
            return parser.parse_args(all_args[:split_at]), all_args[split_at:]

    parser.print_help(sys.stderr)
    print("No command provided", file=sys.stderr)
    raise SystemExit(-1)
```

That works for me, but next to the clumsy extra `MyArgumentParser` needed just to be able to manually handle parser errors I now need to manually classify mistakes, since an `ArgumentError` turns into something that occurs naturally.

So is there a way to tell `argparse` to parse only until the first positional argument and then stop even if there are arguments it knows after that one?

Comment: What exactly is the issue with `--`? That nomenclature seems easier for all parties involved.

Comment: You've discovered the only tricks - '--' and `parse_known_args`.  There is another one, `nargs='...' (REMAINDER), but that's now undocumented since it's a bit buggy.

Comment: "So here it would be much harder to manually identify data2 to be a value for the second --file argument, and bar to be the first positional argument." - Yes, that is the exact problem I see here, and I think it is a design issue. **What rule do you want the code to use**, in order to decide that `data2` is a value for the second `--file` argument, while `bar` is a separate thing? Should it be based on `bar` being in a list of known sub-commands? Should it be based on expecting `--file` to use exactly one subsequent value? Something else?

Comment: (To be honest, `argparse` is definitely not my favourite standard library module, and it is on my short list of things to redesign/reimplement as part of my critique of the standard library.)

Comment: @hpaulj: there are two problems with `--`. First is it's plainly superfluous. From the arguments I could already see, where the extra command starts, it's just a shortcoming of `argparse` I want to workaround. Second it might also be an argument to `bar`, so I still had to deal with a set of arguments which is not fully "mine"

Comment: `subparsers` is a positional argument.  Once the parsing is passed to the specified subparser, the main one does not resume parsing.  Notice that subparsers are handled by a custom action class.  I can imagine writing a Action subclass that acts like a stripped down subparsers.  `subparsers` has a special `nargs='+...'` (undocumented).

Comment: With a subparser I'd have to introduce a special element as well (like e.g. `foo -v --file out.log run bar -v --some arg`). That's an option indeed but I'd like to do this only if there is a proved reason why I can't avoid it.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: in my example `bar` is not just some positional argument to `foo` but it's the name of another executable. Like with `strace`: `strace --arg-for strace ./some_executable --arg-for another-executable`

Comment: `argparse` does not "know" what various strings represent to you or the following code.  They are just strings.  At a top level it classifies the strings as `options` or `arguments` (based on the dash), and then it alternates processing "positionals" and "optionals", handing out strings based on their `nargs`.  There's no short-circuiting that iteration except by errors, help-style exit, and subparsers.  In contrast in `optparse`, each option is given all the remaining strings, and only returns the ones it doesn't use.

Answer (score 0):

Define a parser:

```
In [3]: parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
   ...: parser.add_argument('--file', action='append')
   ...: parser.add_argument('-f')
   ...: parser.add_argument('rest', nargs=argparse.PARSER);
```

The only thing special is this 'rest' with an undocumented `nargs` (same used by `subparsers`.  It's like '+', but values, other than the first, can look like flags.

```
In [4]: parser.print_help()
usage: ipykernel_launcher.py [-h] [--file FILE] [-f F] rest ...

positional arguments:
  rest

options:
  -h, --help   show this help message and exit
  --file FILE
  -f F
```

And testing on your of inputs (I didn't account for the `foo` argument):

```
In [5]: args = parser.parse_args('--file=data1 --file data2 -f1 bar -v --number=42 --file=data3'.split())

In [6]: args
Out[6]: Namespace(file=['data1', 'data2'], f='1', rest=['bar', '-v', '--number=42', '--file=data3'])
```

Omit the positional, and we get an error:

```
In [7]: args = parser.parse_args('--file=data1 --file data2 -f1 -v --number=42 --file=data3'.split())
usage: ipykernel_launcher.py [-h] [--file FILE] [-f F] rest ...
ipykernel_launcher.py: error: the following arguments are required: rest
```

Comment: That does not fit my use case, which might have been unclear, so I've explained it a bit more yesterday: the tool I'm writing takes a full arbitrary shell command, which can have _any_ arguments, notably also arguments my tool understands. Thus the comparison to `strace`. `strace -v python -v` is a valid command with the first `-v` going to `strace` and the second to `python`. The approach with a non-optional positional argument would be unable to parse unknown args, and even `parse_known_args()` would cherry-pick items it knows.

Comment: What I showed was a way to define a `positional` that consumes all the following strings.  I did not change processing order.  `argparse` parses the `argv` in order (data driven).  It does not skip strings, look ahead, or scan from the end. Unrecognized flags are put in the `unknown` category.  I tried to show how it handles repeated flags.  It looks like you need to work with `sys.argv` directly, possibly with repeated calls to a parser.  Your processing logic does not fit with `argparse` (and probably not any other third party parser).

Comment: Yeah, I guess this is what I'm currently doing as seen in my "current approach" in the question